# Flutter Image layering

Tags: flutter, image, stack

How to put the image in the front? I am using flutter[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1X0F8.png)

I already tried Positioned Widgets and Alignment and also stack but I don't seems quite get it why it is still the image is in the back and not on the front

Comment: We can't help much if you don't show us your code. In any case the order of the childs in a `Stack` determines who's in front. If your image is the last child in the stack it will be in front

Comment: Hi, Can you help me with my problem. I am a student and want to learn this. Where can I possibly reach you

Comment: Here is the code btw. 

Expanded(
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  Positioned(
                    right: 0,
                    top: -380,
                    child: Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(
                          0), 
                      child: Transform.scale(
                        scale: 0.30, 
                        child: Image.asset(
                          'Image.jpg',

Comment: @RainheartGalario Please edit your question too provide your code rather than posting it in a comment. Please also provide the code of the entire UI layout you want help with, not just the small snippet that you provided where you lay out the `Image`.